Product of two algebraic varieties may not be a variety over a non-algebraically-closed field?
I'm reading Lang's Introduction to Algebraic Geometry.
By an (affine) $k$-variety (where $k$ is some field) he means an irreducible Zariski closed subset of $k^n$.
If $k$ is algebraically closed, the product $X \times Y$ of two $k$-varieties is again a $k$-variety; however, he claims (Ch. 2) that if $k$ is not algebraically closed, the above is no longer true (i.e., $X \times Y$ may be reducible).
Can someone provide an example, please? Over the reals would be best.

Claim: Let $k$ be a field. Let $X\subset k^m$ and $Y\subset k^n$ be irreducible closed subsets in the Zariski topology. Then $X\times Y\subset k^{m+n}$ is again an irreducible closed subset in the Zariski topology.
Caution - the Zariski topology on $k^{m+n}$ (resp $X\times Y$) is not the product of the Zariski topologies on $k^m$ and $k^n$ (resp $X$ and $Y$).
Proof. Closure is fairly obvious - take polynomials in the first $m$ coordinates vanishing on $X$ and polynomials in the last $n$ coordinates vanishing on $Y$. Irreducibility takes a little effort. Write $X\times Y = Z_1\cup Z_2$ for $Z_1,Z_2$ closed subsets of $k^{m+n}$. Let $X_i=\{ x \in X \mid \{x\}\times Y \subset Z_i\}$ for $i=1,2$. These are closed, since $X_i=\bigcap_{y\in Y} Z_i\cap (X\times \{y\})$ (where we identify $X\cong X\times\{y\}$). Their union is also $X$: as $Z_i\cap (\{x\}\times Y)$ is a closed subset of $\{x\}\times Y \cong Y$, and $Z_1\cup Z_2=X\times Y$, we must have that $(Z_1\cap (\{x\}\times Y))\cup (Z_2\cap (\{x\}\times Y)) = \{x\}\times Y) \cong Y$, so either $\{x\}\times Y \subset Z_1$ or $Z_2$ by irreducibility of $Y$. Therefore by irreducibility of $X$, we have $X=X_1$ or $X=X_2$, showing that in fact $X\times Y = Z_1$ or $X\times Y = Z_2$. $\blacksquare$
What's the point of all of this? The point is that in order to demonstrate a situation where the product of varieties is not a variety, you need to keep track of the defining equations. Once you do, the simplest example where the product of two varieties is no longer a variety is that which Sasha has given: $X=Y=\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb C$ as an $\Bbb R$-scheme, which can be seen as the vanishing locus of $x^2+1$ inside $\Bbb A^1_{\Bbb R}$.

In the semi-classical setting where one considers solutions in a large algebraically closed field while keeping the coefficients in a subfield, singletons may fail to be closed. This seems to be the reason why the argument doesn't apply even though it is basically purely topological.

Take $k = \mathbb{R}$ and $X = Y = \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C})$.

It appears to me that the question is about classical varieties, i.e. Zariski-closed subsets of $k^n$ for some field $k$ and $n\in\mathbb N$, rather than varieties in the sense of scheme theory.

$X$ and $Y$ are subvarieties of the affine line with equations $x^2 + 1 = 0$ and $y^2 + 1 = 0$, respectively.

Spec C is not a set of real points. The equation you write define the empty set, and their product is the empty set

I misunderstood Lang's definition of $k$-algebraic set: it is the set of points inside a (sufficiently large) algebraically closed set which are zeros of (finitely many) polynomials in $k$. Thus, $X = {\pm i}$ is a real algebraic set, which is $\mathbb R$-irreducible (and thus an $\mathbb R$-variety) but $X \times X$ is not $\mathbb R$-irreducible.
